# Avoiding retain cycles in tree-like data structure in Objective C (ARC)

Tags: objective-c, tree, automatic-ref-counting

I have a data structure in Objective C with retain cycles, and I'm trying to figure out a reasonable way to break them. None of the usual rules seem to help here (e.g. "use weak for parent relationships") due to the requirements I have for the data structure.

The data structure is essentially a tree. However, I want to ensure that, if *any* of the nodes in the tree is retained, then the entire tree is retained. For example, in this very simple tree:

```
  A
 / \
B   C
```

If someone retains A, B, or C, then the entire tree should be retained and available to walk up/down from any node. The nodes in the tree should only be released when no one is retaining *any* of the nodes.

The only two solutions I have come up with are not very pretty. Does anyone know of a more elegant solution?

For reference, here are the two solutions I've thought of (both of which mess with retainCount, which is gross):

1. Create a TreeHelper object that holds onto all nodes in the tree strongly. All nodes use weak pointers to refer to all other nodes. All nodes in the tree hold onto TreeHelper strongly when their retainCount > 1 and weakly when retainCount == 1. This should work, but requires that we use non-ARC code so we can override retain/release and change the ownership of TreeHelper.
2. Create a TreeHelper object that holds onto all objects in the tree strongly. All nodes use weak pointers to refer to all other nodes and strongly hold TreeHelper. Periodically, it will execute a garbage collection and check the retainCount of all objects. If they are all == 1, then it nils all objects to release them. This should also work, but the garbage collection is not pretty and has some serious thread safety issues.

Comment: Don't use `retainCount`, add a count to the classes. The system `retainCount` is managed/changed by the system as the system needs. Also by not using `retainCount` you can use ARC.

Comment: What @zaph said.   I've had to debug code that switches behaviors on certain `retainCount` values.  It is insanity inducing;  one stray `retain/autorelease` and, suddenly, your caching semantic change code kicks in in the middle of a pool drain instead of in the middle of orderly object graph destruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to stop you from using ARC for your "treehelper" scheme.

First, make your tree opaque. Any accesses to the nodes (which have weak references to their parents to avoid retain cycles) go through methods of the treehelper (maybe call it a TreeWrapper or TreeRef instead).

Whenever any third-party accesses a node, you return a new data structure `NodeWrapper`, which has a strong reference to both the specific node you want, and the root node. The third party establishes a strong reference to this object, not the node itself.

The result is that when the last of these objects is deallocated, the whole tree is deallocated, and as long as one `NodeWrapper` lives, your tree lives, meeting your requirements.

[Never use `retainCount` for *anything*, even if you aren't using ARC.](http://whentouseretaincount.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Good idea; that should work, even if it requires me to refactor a large portion of my API to return wrappers... :/

Comment: Sorry :(... You could maybe mitigate those issues by having your wrapper present itself as a subclass of your node, but actually just forward all the relevant messages to the "real" node, since the client shouldn't actually know or care about the strong reference to the overall tree, or maybe you could use `NSProxy`.